# Host WCF service in console Application

Tags: wcf

I have around 15-20 services - each service has its own contract and implementation file. I want to host all these service in a console app so that it will be easier to debug during development.

Project structure

- Services - Solution

  - ServiceContracts - Project
  - Implementation   - Project
  - ServiceHost      - Windows Service project  -- Already inplace and working fine..
  - ServiceConsoleHost - Project - Currently working on it.

I have an `app.config` file in the ServiceConsoleHost project here the sample text from config file...

```
<service name="TestpricingService" behaviorConfiguration="HostBehavior">
<host>
   <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/testService/pricingService"/>
   </baseAddresses>
</host>
    <!-- use base address provided by host -->
    <endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:820/testService/pricingService"
                      binding="netTcpBinding"
                      bindingConfiguration="HostBinding"
                      contract="Test.Services.Contracts.IpricingService" />
    <!-- the mex endpoint is exposed at http://localhost:8000/testService/purchasing/mex -->
    <endpoint address="mex"
    binding="mexHttpBinding"
    contract="IMetadataExchange" />
</service>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="HostBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="PooledHostBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
      <ObjectPoolingServiceBehavior minPoolSize="0" maxPoolSize="5" idleTimeOut="30000"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Need code to host these services in console app - in loop.

Comment: What do you mean by "in loop"? Also in your app.config you have a net.tcp binding and a mexhttpbinding and your service name is not fully qualified.

Comment: What i'm trying to do here is... trying to host all those 15 services in console app.. instead of creating host object for each service - can we use servicehost collection for somthing like that?

Comment: want to host service using nettcp binding..

Comment: When you say single host are you referring to a single port for your net tcp binding. If that is the case then look at this article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa395195.aspx

Comment: One `ServiceHost` can host exactly **one service** - so if you need to host 15 services, you need 15 instances of `ServiceHost`

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for self-hosted services. See [MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731758.aspx) on self-hosting using `ServiceHost`.

Also take a look at [enumerating WCF configuration bindings](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/markgabarra/archive/2006/04/27/585607.aspx). Here is an SO post which describes [enumerating WCF service and endpoint bindings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5993985/175679).

Comment: I already looked at that -- all the example are showing how to host single service - in my case i've 15 services and i dont want to create a host object for each service.

Comment: @venky - you need a separate `ServiceHost` for each service you have.

Comment: Can we use serviceHost as collection to hold all services?

Answer (score 1):

as everyone mentioned you need 15 ServiceHosts to host 15 services. However they are not blocking. If you notice the MSDN code just sits waiting for a keypress whilst the service is running. This means all the service code is running on separate threads. So creating and hosting 15 services is not an issue. You dont need a "loop" as that is already handled once you do ServiceHost.Open().