# How to register two WCF service contracts with autofac

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a WCF service that implements two service contracts...

```
public class MyService : IService1, IService2
```

and I am self-hosting the service...

```
host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));
```

Everything was working fine when the service implemented only one service contract, but when I attempt to set up autofac to register both like this:

```
host.AddDependencyInjectionBehavior<IService1>(_container);
host.AddDependencyInjectionBehavior<IService2>(_container);
```

... it throws an exception on the second one, reporting:

*The value could not be added to the collection, as the collection already contains an item of the same type: 'Autofac.Integration.Wcf.AutofacDependencyInjectionServiceBehavior'. This collection only supports one instance of each type.*

At first glance I thought this was saying my two contracts were somehow being seen as the same type but on second reading I believe it is saying that the 
AutofacDependencyInjectionServiceBehavior is the type in question, i.e. I cannot use it twice!

And yet, I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16753990/115690) that explicitly showed using it multiple times in a slightly different form:

```
foreach (var endpoint in host.Description.Endpoints)
{
  var contract = endpoint.Contract;
  Type t = contract.ContractType;
  host.AddDependencyInjectionBehavior(t, container);
}
```

Unfortunately, that gave the very same error message.

Is it possible to register more than one service contract on one service and, if so, how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact you can register multiple endpoint for a single host with Autofac.

That is true that you cannot add multiple `AutofacDependencyInjectionServiceBehavior` but this behaviour iterates through all the endpoints and registers them in the `ApplyDispatchBehavior` method: [source](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/source/browse/Core/Source/Autofac.Integration.Wcf/AutofacDependencyInjectionServiceBehavior.cs)

In order to make this work you need to register your service `AsSelf()`

```
builder.RegisterType<MyService>();
```

Then you can configure your endpoint normally:

```
host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MyService));
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService1), binding, string.Empty);
host.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(IService2), binding, string.Empty);
```

And finally you need to call the `AddDependencyInjectionBehavior` with the sevicehost type itself:

```
host.AddDependencyInjectionBehavior<MyService>(container);
```

Here is a small [sample project](https://gist.github.com/nemesv/f36b27826a401eec8f82) (based on the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/WcfIntegration)) which demonstrates this behavior.

Comment: Thank you--I should have thought to try that! I am glad you proved me wrong :-)

Answer (score 0):

*Update (the bold text) based on @nemesv's answer:*

Further investigation revealed that *with autofac* one *cannot* register multiple endpoints on a single ServiceHost **if one registers the WCF service contracts**.
(See @nemesv's answer for the correct way to do it.)

*Here is why:*

Either form of this extension method...

```
host.AddDependencyInjectionBehavior<IService1>(_container);
host.AddDependencyInjectionBehavior(t, container);
```

...resolves down to adding a ServiceBehavior (according to Alex Meyer-Gleaves [initial announcement of WCF integration](http://alexmg.com/post/2010/05/16/Making-Self-Hosting-with-Autofac-WCF-Integration-easier.aspx) in autofac)...

```
host.Description.Behaviors.Add(behavior);
```

Now this [Behaviors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicedescription.behaviors.aspx) property is an instance of [KeyedByTypeCollection<TItem>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404549.aspx), which can hold only only one object of a given type. Since the behavior being added will always be an instance of `AutofacDependencyInjectionServiceBehavior`, one can therefore only add one endpoint.

QED

The workaround is to use multiple ServiceHosts, each with a single endpoint.

*(As a point of interest, I would be curious to know the impact on performance and scalability between those two approaches.)*

Comment: Wouldn't inheriting from AutofacDependencyInjectionServiceBehavior and readding instance of that help?